# Unique function whose product is a unique monoid element?

Tags: category-theory, definition, monoid

Let $P$ be the free monoid on a set $X$. Given $p \in P$, this induces a unique function $f : [n] \to X$ with $\prod_{i\in[n]} f(i) = p$. Does this function have a name?

Comment: There is no such function $f$ if the length of $p$ is not equal to $n$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin There exists unique $n \in \mathbb N$ and $f : [n] \to X$...

Comment: @WillSherwood You seem to be saying that the free monoid is isomorphic to the standard construction of the free monoid in terms of words. I would just call $f$ the word that represents $p$.

Comment: This is an *extensionality principle*: words $p$ are completely determined by their letters $f(i)$ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A bit of notation and terminology. The free monoid on the set $X$ is usually denoted by $X^*$. The set $X$ is the *alphabet*, its elements are *letters*. The elements of $X^*$ are called *words*.

Let $p = a_1 \dotsm a_n$ be a word, where $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are letters. Then $n$ is the length of $p$ (also denoted $|p|$). The letter $a_i$ is the letter of $p$ at position $i$. Thus, if you insist  to give a name to your function $f: \{1, \ldots, |p|\} \to X$, I would suggest to call it the *position map*.

Comment: Your sentence “Let $p = a_1 \cdots a_n$ be a word is equivalent to the existence of those unique $f, n$. I was hoping for a more categorical explanation of $f$.. I was thinking something like, for each $p \in X^*$ and $n’ \in \mathbb N$, either $p = (\prod_{i \in [n’]} x_i) p’$ with $x_i \in X$ and $p’ \in X^*$, or not; if not, though, there does not exist such a decomposition with $n’ + 1$. Define $|p|$ as the maximal $n$ for which such a decomposition of $p$ exists, and $x_i : [|p|] \to X$ as $f$. This process works in other algebraic objects and so I thought it may have a more general name.